# User needs admin approval after registration for login and redirect to login page right after registration

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

In my Laravel 5.5 application with default auth system,I am trying to implement a login procedure like this,

1.I have a `is_approved` field in `users` table which is default 0;

2.If admin approved a user, it will be 1 and user can log in.

3.User will be redirected to login page after the registration with a message "You 
  have been successfully registered.Please wait for the admin approval".

So when a user registered he should be redirected to login page instead of home and if he tries to login in the login page with email and password it should say "You are not approved yet ! ".

What i need to modify for this in Laravel authentication system ?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. You can add a `protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)` in your login controller to override the equivalent [trait one](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L74) or you can add a middleware to check whether a user has logged in and log them out if they are not approved and many many other ways. First you should make an attempt and then ask a question when you have a concrete programming issue.

Comment: I register the user and it takes him to home.I am not quite sure  which trait or controller i need to modify for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I override and modify the   `register` method in my `RegisterController`  ,

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You have been successfully registered!. Please wait for the admin approval');
    }
```

and in my `LoginController` I override and modify the  `credentials` method,

```
public function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'is_approved' => 1,
        ];
    }
```

Its working perfectly !